# Is there a general script to automatically update packages downloaded from the Internet?

Tags: software-installation, updates, scripts

### Reopen request:

Yes, this is marked as duplicate.

** What I am asking is a shell script that can help me achieve updating packages with `.deb` and `.tar.gz`, but ***NOT*** how `.deb` will affect `apt-get update`, and ***NOT just*** manually compile the `.tar.gz` and manually update the package.

As I've mentioned before:

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431905/how-does-update-work-with-programs-installed-from-deb-file) queries the adding of PPA in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, which is not what I wanted, because I said there is no PPA available already. Also, I *don't* like using other PPAs, I prefer a script that is viewable and editable by me at any time I want.

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7659/can-i-update-software-installed-from-source-code-directly) shows no sign of (even) automatically downloading the `.tar.gz` packages. Also, what it talks about is *manually* updating source code packages, but what I want is a custom script that I can *automatically* download the source code, compile it and also *automatically* install it.

For some more information, I already know the existence of Arch Linux's AUR, and according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599135/does-ubuntu-have-an-equivalent-to-the-aur-arch-user-repository) which previously also flagged suggested duplicate, it is saying that an equivalent to Arch Linux's AUR is Ubuntu's PPA, which is *not* what I wanted.

I am now requesting to reopen this question. Please, and **please** understand what I *want*, not just marking some topics I *don't* need, and then say *"This is a duplicate question"*.

Also check out [the meta thread regarding this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17301/closed-as-duplicate-but-the-duplicates-do-not-solve-my-problem) on this.

---

### Question:

I know that we can automatically update packages using `apt` or `apt-get` if they are installed via PPA.

However, recently I found out that a package I installed, which is downloaded from the Internet in `.deb` format, is seriously outdated. There is no offical or unoffical PPA available for that program.

Also, another program that I complied long ago (also downloaded from the Internet, `.tar.gz` format) is also outdated.

Is it possible to have a shell script that can automatically check for updates online, download the `.deb` and `.tar.gz` packages, automatically compile it, and install it in Ubuntu?

---

### For reference only:

1. Preferred: `wget`, `make`, crontab
2. I understand the risk of using such scripts (risk of malicious downloads), I can personally bear it because I know how to remove infections when the system got infected by viruses.
3. If anyone want me to specify a package I want to update, please use [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/downloads) and [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/page_download/) (it's `.tar.gz` package).

Comment: I can't see why not.  i've written scripts that search online (specific site) & wget later files than whatever i already had.   I can't see why it can't be cron'd, then dpkg/make... if downloaded file was of that 'file` type  - but I don't think I'd want to run it myself.  I'd rather script notify me (email etc) & suggest/request permission to install.

Comment: The use of PPAs is already unsafe, but a script that downloads executable software from the internet and installs it without any user control? I consider this plain dangerous and strongly suggest you make it at least  ask you before installing anything.

Comment: I can see trouble being given an invitation -- I hope you know what your asking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does update work with programs installed from .deb file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431905/how-does-update-work-with-programs-installed-from-deb-file) and [Can I update software installed from source code directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7659/can-i-update-software-installed-from-source-code-directly)

Comment: Then it's too broad. Software can be downloaded from a veriety of places, built in a variety of ways, have a variety of possibly changing dependencies.

Comment: No, what I want is just a shell script that can achieve updating by downloading and compiling and installing automatically.

Comment: Of what? From where? How?

Comment: A pretty general script that I can use. If very needed to be specific, take WPS Office as an example. It's a `.deb` file, and I want the script to automatically check for updates, download it and install it.

Comment: You're essentially asking from something like Arch Linux's AUR, except you haven't given any source of necessary information like the download location, dependency information, build instructions, and haven't said anything about how to obtain those.

Comment: Yes, of course I know Arch Linux's AUR, I just wonder if I can do similar things in Ubuntu.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/599135/does-ubuntu-have-an-equivalent-to-the-aur-arch-user-repository.

Comment: For WPS, you could do `wget -qO- http://wps-community.org/downloads | pup "a:contains(\"$(dpkg-architecture -q DEB_HOST_ARCH)\") attr{href}" | head -n1` to get the latest deb file's URL, then download it and use `apt install`; but obviously that depends on the site structure and may or may not be generalisable to other software sites.

Comment: I insist, the answer to your question is already given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599135/does-ubuntu-have-an-equivalent-to-the-aur-arch-user-repository): *Yes, PPAs. That's the closest you can get right now. If you don't think they're equivalent enough for you, then the answer right now is simply "**no**".*

Comment: I am asking for *shell scripts*; not *PPAs*. If ***no***, why not answer ***no***, but close it as irrelevant ^duplicate^ topics????

Comment: Well because the answer **no** is already given to multiple similar questions. They may not be 1:1 identical of course, but they give all the answers possible.

Comment: Maybe tarbells is a no, but how about `.deb`s? muru already suggested a comment that may solve the problem, and if question are not 1:1 identical and a "no" can be given to answers, then why not open a thread with an answer "no" and then direct all posts like this to the thread?

Comment: I am not trying to be rude. Instead, I want to point out that this is not the type of questions the previous topics are asking. I want to state that people should not mark something duplicate just because they are of the same topic.

Comment: Please post suggestions how to improve Ask Ubuntu on https://meta.askubuntu.com.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen to then close as "too broad" since you're asking for a general approach which doesn't exist barring the training of an artificial intelligence to do what package maintainers and system administrators are doing today.

Comment: I would not object.

Comment: Probably your best option would be to look at the LFS or gentoo methods of updating.